# partition of a vector space with the condition $x+y \neq z$ in any group

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, set-partition

I find an equivalence for a linear algebra problem which seems not easy.

Consider the vector space $$ \mathbb{Z}_2^n $$ for a natural number n. We want to partition $$ \mathbb{Z}_2^n \setminus\{(0,\dots.0)\} $$ into the subsets with the property that if $x,y,z$ are in the same group, then we have $ x+y+z \neq 0 $. The question is that can the number of partition groups be $ o(n) $?
But I still can't find an example with less than $n$ groups(partition into n groups in easy).

Comment: Can you describe to us how you achieved $n$ groups? It may be obvious, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: We can do this by considering complements of n maximal subspaces whose characteristic vectors are linearly independent. For instance, Consider the i-th group consists of vectors whose i-th component is none-zero.